# Compute Sum of a Sequence in java

Tags: java

I have a task to make a code to compute 1*2 + 3*4 +5*6 + ... + (2*n-1)*(2n) 
... here is my code

```
public class Tetris {
    public static int sumOfProd(int n)  {
     int sum = (2*n-1)*(2*n);
     return sum;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n=1; n<10; n++){ 
            System.out.println(sumOfProd(n));

        }

        }
    }
```

the code works but it does not compute the sum for all iterations .
my output is

```
2
12
30
56
90
132
182
240
306
```

But I want to print out the sum of all these values .. I tried to put sum++ in the sumOfProd method but it did not work and I tried to put a for loop but it was wrong ...
How to fix that?
thanks

Comment: sum each resulting int returned from sumOfProd

Comment: The expression for variable `int sum` has no `+` sign anywhere: `(2*n-1)*(2*n);` Doesn't it surprise you? It should...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Where would you put a `+` in that expression to solve the problem?

Comment: `IntStream.range(1, 10).map(n -> (2*n-1)*(2*n)).sum()`

Comment: @ScottHunter That's my point! There's no place for a plus in there, yet it's assigned to a variable called `sum`. OP should realize that the expression represents a product, so the variable needs to be called `product` instead. A natural step after that is to introduce a variable to represent a `sum`, and start adding products to it.

Comment: Use a real language, like C#.

Comment: @Krythic: use a real brain. It helps, sometimes. ;) And you don't even need to switch your coding language. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursion or an iteration sum.
Since you already have an iteration, modifying the code in the latter way should be easier:

```
public class Tetris {
    public static int sumOfProd(int n)  {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 2;
        while (i <= n){ 
            sum = sum + (2*i-1)*(2*i);
            i = i+2;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumOfProd(10));
    }

}
```

Comment: If there is a method called *sum*OfProd, then *that* is where you do the summing; not inside the *main* method.

Comment: @java: modified, I forgot you should add 2 instead of 1 every cycle. You can retry. :)

Comment: thank you , it works but why you put i = i+2; what is the purpose of it??

Comment: @java: since your task is to multiply an integer N with N-1, adding only 1 during the loop (like you did using i++) would result in duplicates (e.g.: 2*1+3*2+4*3 etc.). If you add 2 instead (thus using i = i+2 in place of i++ during the loop), everything works fine (e.g.: 2*1+4*3+6*5 etc.). :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your main to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int n=1; n<10; n++){
            sum += sumOfProd(n);
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
```

I have added int variable sum, which starting value is 0. And for every for iteration we add what sumOfProd returns.

Comment: If there is a method called *sum*OfProd, then *that* is where you do the summing; not inside the *main* method.

Answer (score 0):

What results do you expect?

```
public static int sumOfProd(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 2 * n; i += 2) {
        sum += i * (i - 1);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

produces

```
2
14
44
100
190
322
504
744
1050
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
public static int sumOfProd(int n)  {
     int sum;
    if(n>0)
    {
    sum = (2*n-1)*(2*n)+sumOfProd(n-1);
    }
    else
    {
         sum =0;
    }
     return sum;

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n =10;
     System.out.println(sumOfProd(n));

}
```

Comment: This leads to duplicated values during the recursion (see comments to my answer). You should call recursively with sumOfProd(n-2), and modify the condition of the if statement to n>1.